# Solving a picture jumble!

Tags: algorithm, image

What algorithm would you make a computer use, if you want to solve a picture jumble?

You can always argue in terms of efficiency of the algorithm, but here I am really looking at what approaches to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Is "picture jumble" the same as jigsaw puzzle?

Comment: jigsaw puzzle or sliding tile puzzle?

Comment: Can we assume (as the answers posted so far do) that each edge can match exactly one other edge? That simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is to define an indexing vocabulary for each face of a jigsaw puzzle, such that the index of a right-facing edge can can tell you what the index of a corresponding left-facing edge is (e.g, a simple vocabulary: "convex" and "concave", with "convex" on a face implying "concave" on a matching opposite face), and then classify each piece according to the indexing vocabulary.  The finer the vocabulary, the more discrimantory the face-matching and the faster your algorthm will go, however you implement it.  (For instance, you may have "flat edge, straight-edge-leans-left, straight-edge-leans-right, concave, convex, knob, knob-hole, ...).  We assume that the indexing scheme abstracts the actual shape of the edge, and that there is a predicate "exactly-fits(piece1,edge1,piece2,edge2)" that is true only if the edges exactly match. We further assume that there is at most one exact match of a piece with a particular edge.

The goal is grow a set of regions, e.g., a set of connected pieces, until it is no longer possible to grow the regions.  We first mark all pieces with unique region names, 1 per piece, and all edges as unmatched.  Then we enumerate the piece edges in any order.  For each enumerated piece P with edge E, use the indexing scheme to select potentially matching piece/edge pairs.  Check the exactly-fits predicate; at most one piece Q, with edge F, exactly-matches.  Combine the regions for P and Q together to make a large region.  Repeat.  I think this solves the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Solving a jigsaw puzzle can basically be reduced to matching like edges to like edges. In a true jigsaw puzzle only one pair of pieces can properly be interlocked along a particular edge, and each piece will have corners so that you know where a particular side starts and ends.

Thus, just find the endpoints of each edge and select a few control points. Then iterate through all pieces with unbound edges until you find the right one. When there are no more unbound edges, you have solved the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Ira Baxter's answer, another way of conceptualizing the problem is to think about the jigsaw puzzle as a graph, where each piece is a node and each iterface with another piece is an edge.

For example if you were designing a puzzle game, storing the "answer" this way would make "check if this fits" code a lot faster, since it could be reduced to some sort of hash-lookup.

Answer (score 0):

.1 Find **2x2-grams** such that all four edges will fit. Then, evaluate how well the image content matches with each other.

```
  P1 <--> P2
  ^       ^
  |       |
  v       v
  P3 <--> P4
```

.2 Tag **orientations** (manually or heuristically), but only use them as heuristics scores (for ranking), not as definitive search criteria.

.3 **Shape Context**