# Joining the puzzle out of raw images

Tags: algorithm, image, puzzle, brute-force

I have "2000 RAW Images" 52x52 pixels, that correspond to the pieces of a puzzle representing a 4000x1250 pixel image. Also the images file names are bunch of numbers generated, it seems there something related to brute-forcing ?

As i mentioned, i need to join the images together to complete the puzzle. And i have no idea where to start, any help ?

The Images are RGB 24 bits.

Comment: You may find this answer on SO helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124968/1278792

Comment: aha thanks, just checked it out. It seems helpful, will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a fun project. Here's how I would tackle it:

1. Try to create some sort of profile of the edges of each image. It could for instance be based on the RGB-values of the edge-pixels.
2. Create a mapping from such a profile to four sets containing the images whose left / bottom / right / top edges match the profile.

   ```
   ...
   xyz -> { { images whose left   edge has profile xyz },
            { images whose bottom edge has profile xyz },
            { images whose right  edge has profile xyz },
            { images whose top    edge has profile xyz } }
   ...
   ```
3. Now for each image, compute its 4 edge profiles. Try to pair it up with each image in the corresponding set. If it's left profile is `xyz`, try to put it beside each image whose right profile is `xyz`.

Comment: At point three you have basically created a similarity graph and the problem transforms to just finding a [stable matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_matching).

Comment: It's harder than i thought. I never worked on images before, seems im gonna spend some time reading.

Comment: @aioobe; It seems, am not going to be able to solve, even thought you're solution is true. Can you update your post with more details ? Will be really helpful.

Comment: Could you upload a zip file with the images somewhere?

Comment: @aioobe I will upload the images when i get back home.

Comment: @aioobe It would be great if you can help out, as i don't have much of information about image processing. This is the link for the images http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64579490/puzzle.rar

Comment: Something is weird with the image data. Each file is 8163 bytes, but it says that it should be 52*52 pixels, 3 bytes/pixel (52*52*3 = 8112). In fact, 8163/3 (which ought to be the number of pixels) is not even a square number, so what *is* the edge length?

Comment: @aioobe The settings to open the raw blocks in Photoshop are
52x52 pixels, 8 bit, 3 channels, interleaved, header size = 0, you'll see that they are squares.

Comment: @aioobe What i think is "The files are padded at the end with 51bits of empty bits (all 0)"

Comment: @aioobe Managed to get a little near the solution, i actually noticed that some files needs to be rotated. It's actually a hard exercise. Will see what will i achieve.

Comment: Oh, wow... then it's tougher! I may have a look at it when I have time... I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally compare the pieces borders colors and statistically match the next piece of puzzle.

1. Code a function which return only the first pixel row or column of your puzzle piece.
2. Code a function that will return the number of matching pixel (rgb color values) between 2 borders according the the 3 closest neighbors.
3. Loop for each puzzle position and compare foreach possible next puzzle piece. keep the puzzle piece which would have the most closest pixels of the same color.

I expect that you'll be ok to get the 1 pixel border of the image and compare the rgb values.